# Absolute value of a complex number/function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have a very generic question (maybe I am wrong because I am trying to be too generic): When I compute the absolute value of any function however difficult and complex it is, should I expect to have NO IMAGINARY PART as an output?

However, what if for instance the solver gives me the output in the form of Isinh(Isomething)? As you all know, there are many relationship between hyperbolic functions and trigonometric. Is this the only case in which I may have imaginary unit in my output? Look at the following output coming from the integral of an absoulute value (I see I)

```
(*  (1/(3 Sqrt[2]))((-2 + 2 I) EllipticF[
ArcSin[((-1)^(1/4) b)/(-Cos[1] + Sin[1])], -1] (Cos[1] - Sin[1])^3 + 
b Sqrt[3 + 2 b^4 - Cos[4] - 4 Sin[2]])  *)
```

Comment: Yes.  If we have $z=x+iy$, where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, then $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and is purely real.

Answer (score 2):

By definition the absolute value is  **real not negative function** that has some other properties (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value_%28algebra%29)). So it cannot be an imaginary number.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. Let $f$ be a complex-valued function. Then for every $z$ in the domain of $f$, $f(z) = x + i y$ for some $x$, $y \in \mathbb{R}$, so $|f(z)| = |x+iy|=x^2 + y^2$, which is real.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $|i|=1$.

So, yes, you shouldn't expect any $i$ in your outcome.

Answer (score 0):

However, what if for instance the solver gives me the output in the form of I*sinh(I*something)? As you all know, there are many relationship between hyperbolic functions and trigonometric. Is this the only case in which I may have imaginary unit in my output? Look at the following output coming from the integral of an absoulute value (I see I)

```
(*  (1/(3 Sqrt[2]))((-2 + 2 I) EllipticF[
ArcSin[((-1)^(1/4) b)/(-Cos[1] + Sin[1])], -1] (Cos[1] - Sin[1])^3 + 
b Sqrt[3 + 2 b^4 - Cos[4] - 4 Sin[2]])  *)
```